Combining Multiple PySpark DataFrames Dynamically: Incorporating Static Columns with Yearly Dynamic Columns for Each DataFrame
I possess multiple PySpark DataFrames that need to be concatenated or unionized to produce a final DataFrame with the following structure:
Input:
df1 :[colA, colB, colC, avg_salary_y2020]
df2 :[colA, colB, colC, avg_salary_y2021]
df3 :[colA, colB, colC, avg_salary_y2022]

Output:
df_final: [colA, colB, colC, avg_salary_y2020, avg_salary_y2021, avg_salary_y2022]

Is there an elegant solution to accomplish this task?

I built this solution:
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from functools import reduce

# Collect all DataFrames into a list
all_dataframes = list(all_spark_dfs.values())

# Check if there are any DataFrames to process
if not all_dataframes:
    raise ValueError("No DataFrames found in 'all_spark_dfs'.")

# Efficient check for non-empty DataFrames
non_empty_dfs = [df for df in all_dataframes if df.head(1)]

# If there's only one non-empty DataFrame, skip union
if len(non_empty_dfs) == 1:
    combined_df = non_empty_dfs[0]
else:
    combined_df = reduce(DataFrame.unionByName, non_empty_dfs)

# Ensure the 'year' column exists and has the correct data type
if 'year' not in combined_df.columns:
    raise ValueError("The 'year' column is missing from the combined DataFrame.")
    
# Check if the 'average_hourly_wage_($)' column exists
if 'average_hourly_wage_($)' not in combined_df.columns:
    raise ValueError("The 'average_hourly_wage_($)' column is missing from the combined DataFrame.")

# Pivot the 'year' column and aggregate the 'average_hourly_wage_($)' by year
pivoted_df3 = (combined_df.groupBy("id", "area_code", "occupation_code", "job_characteristic_code")
    .pivot("year", [str(year) for year in range(2014, 2024)])
    .agg(F.first("average_hourly_wage_($)").alias("average_hourly_wage_($)")))

# Rename the pivoted columns for the desired output format
for year in range(2014, 2024):
    pivoted_df3 = pivoted_df3.withColumnRenamed(f"{year}", f"average_hourly_wage_($)_{year}")

# Display the final DataFrame schema and result
pivoted_df3.printSchema()
pivoted_df3.show()

I hope it would be helpful for anyone out there.

I'm glad you found a solution. Since you asked for an elegant one:
Based on the input/output you provided:
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

dataframes = [df1, df2, df3]
df_final = reduce(lambda df1, df2: df1.join(df2, on=['colA', 'colB', 'colC'], how='left'), dataframes)

But this doesn't address the dynamic year col.
Therefore, and based on your solution:
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, col

def union_dfs_dynamic_cols(dataframes: list, year_col: str, salary_col: str) -> DataFrame:
    """union a list of dataframes, dynamically add missing cols, rename salary cols by year."""
    
    union_df = None

    # iterate over dataframes to align columns and rename salary column based on the year
    for df in dataframes:
        # verify year column exists
        if year_col not in df.columns:
            raise ValueError(f"Year column '{year_col}' is missing in the DataFrame.")
        
        # get distinct year val
        year_value = df.select(year_col).distinct().first()[0]

        # rename salary col to dynamically include year
        df = df.withColumnRenamed(salary_col, f"avg_hourly_wage_{year_value}")

        # add missing col with None values for alignment
        if union_df is None:
            # initialize union df if first df
            union_df = df
        else:
            # get set of cols in current union df and new df
            current_columns = set(union_df.columns)
            new_columns = set(df.columns)
            
            # add missing cols to each df for compatibility
            for col_name in new_columns - current_columns:
                union_df = union_df.withColumn(col_name, lit(None))
            for col_name in current_columns - new_columns:
                df = df.withColumn(col_name, lit(None))
            
            # union current df with union df
            union_df = union_df.unionByName(df)
    return union_df

# test
dataframes = [df1, df2, df3]
final_df = union_dfs_dynamic_cols(dataframes, year_col="year", salary_col="average_hourly_wage_($)")

Key optimizations:

Dynamic column handling with set operations to add missing columns instead of manually naming them.
Fewer loops and code duplication


you could list all unique columns and then create null columns for the non-existent ones
here's an example
# input dataframes
data1_sdf = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 1, 1)], ['a', 'b', 'y1'])
data2_sdf = spark.createDataFrame([(2, 2, 2)], ['a', 'b', 'y2'])
data3_sdf = spark.createDataFrame([(3, 3, 3)], ['a', 'b', 'y3'])

# list all unique columns
allcols = list(set(data1_sdf.columns + data2_sdf.columns + data3_sdf.columns))
# ['a', 'y2', 'y1', 'y3', 'b']

# create non-existent columns and use UnionByName
create_cols = lambda x: [func.lit(None).alias(k) for k in allcols if k not in x.columns]

data1_sdf.select('*', *create_cols(data1_sdf)). \
    unionByName(data2_sdf.select('*', *create_cols(data2_sdf))). \
    unionByName(data3_sdf.select('*', *create_cols(data3_sdf))). \
    show()

# +---+---+----+----+----+
# |  a|  b|  y1|  y2|  y3|
# +---+---+----+----+----+
# |  1|  1|   1|null|null|
# |  2|  2|null|   2|null|
# |  3|  3|null|null|   3|
# +---+---+----+----+----+


you could also do a full outer join
data1_sdf. \
    join(data2_sdf, ['a', 'b'], 'full'). \
    join(data3_sdf, ['a', 'b'], 'full'). \
    show()

# +---+---+----+----+----+
# |  a|  b|  y1|  y2|  y3|
# +---+---+----+----+----+
# |  1|  1|   1|null|null|
# |  2|  2|null|   2|null|
# |  3|  3|null|null|   3|
# +---+---+----+----+----+

